# Grouping elements in array by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, sorting, properties

During work, I was given this task: to group elements with similar properties in the array.

In general, the problem is as follows:

```
var list = [
    {name: "1", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
    {name: "2", lastname: "foo", age: "13"},
    {name: "3", lastname: "foo1", age: "11"},
    {name: "4", lastname: "foo", age: "11"},
    {name: "5", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
    {name: "6", lastname: "foo", age: "16"},
    {name: "7", lastname: "foo1", age: "13"},
    {name: "8", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
    {name: "9", lastname: "foo", age: "13"},
    {name: "0", lastname: "foo", age: "16"}
];
```

If I group this elements by `lastname` and `age`, I will get this result:

```
var result = [
    [
        {name: "1", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
        {name: "5", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"}, 
        {name: "8", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "2", lastname: "foo", age: "13"},
        {name: "9", lastname: "foo", age: "13"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "3", lastname: "foo1", age: "11"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "4", lastname: "foo", age: "11"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "6", lastname: "foo", age: "16"},
        {name: "0", lastname: "foo", age: "16"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "7", lastname: "foo1", age: "13"}
    ]         
];
```

After some experimentation, I came to the following solution:

```
    Array.prototype.groupByProperties = function(properties){
        var arr = this;
        var groups = [];
        for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i<len; i+=1){
            var obj = arr[i];
            if(groups.length == 0){
                groups.push([obj]);
            }
            else{
                var equalGroup = false;
                for(var a = 0, glen = groups.length; a<glen;a+=1){
                    var group = groups[a];
                    var equal = true;
                    var firstElement = group[0];
                    properties.forEach(function(property){

                        if(firstElement[property] !== obj[property]){
                            equal = false;
                        }

                    });
                    if(equal){
                        equalGroup = group;
                    }
                }
                if(equalGroup){
                    equalGroup.push(obj);
                }
                else {
                    groups.push([obj]);
                }
            }
        }
        return groups;
    };
```

This solution works, but is this a right and best way? It still looks a little ugly to me.

Comment: There is npm module named [group-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/group-array) that matches the same requirement.

Comment: Why not just sort the array based on those values?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I felt compelled to write that you probably should combine forEach and map with the answer of Alexey Lebedev.

```
function groupBy( array , f )
{
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach( function( o )
  {
    var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o );  
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  })
}

var result = groupBy(list, function(item)
{
  return [item.lastname, item.age];
});
```

Answer (score 25):

The main problem with your function is quadratic time complexity in the worst case. Also, if we first implement a general `groupBy` function, grouping by properties becomes trivial.

```
function arrayFromObject(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        arr.push(obj[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}

function groupBy(list, fn) {
    var groups = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var group = JSON.stringify(fn(list[i]));
        if (group in groups) {
            groups[group].push(list[i]);
        } else {
            groups[group] = [list[i]];
        }
    }
    return arrayFromObject(groups);
}

var result = groupBy(list, function(item) {
    return [item.lastname, item.age];
});
```

You might want to add `hasOwnProperty` check into `arrayFromObject`, if your coding convention doesn't forbid extending object prototype.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider passing a serialization function to your groupBy method. With toString there are several problems: `item1 = { lastName : [1,2], age : 3 }` and `item2 = { lastName : 1, age : [2,3] }` and `item3 = { lastName : '1,2', age : 3 }` will all be put in the same group in your example.

Comment: Tibos: you're right, that's a bug waiting to happen. I've changed `toString()` to `JSON.stringify()`. The speed is comparable, assuming that JSON is implemented natively.

Comment: Using the stringify as the key is brilliant, +1

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev vey brilliant solution! Assumed I want to lowercase so to ignore case how to?

Comment: @loretoparisi `return [item.lastname.toLowerCase(), item.age];`

Answer (score 10):

I find the functional aspect of JavaScript to be a big advantage. When it comes to looping, `Array.prototype.forEach` and cousins can help your code be more descriptive:

```
Array.prototype.defineProperty('groupByProperties', {
    value : function(properties){                       
        // will contain grouped items
        var result = []; 

        // iterate over each item in the original array
        this.forEach(function(item){
            // check if the item belongs in an already created group
            var added = result.some(function(group){
                // check if the item belongs in this group
                var shouldAdd = properties.every(function(prop){
                    return (group[0][prop] === item[prop]);
                });
                // add item to this group if it belongs 
                if (shouldAdd) {
                    group.push(item);
                }
                // exit the loop when an item is added, continue if not
                return shouldAdd;
            });

            // no matching group was found, so a new group needs to be created for this item
            if (!added) {
                result.push([item]);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

While i don't consider it a best practice to add custom functionality to predefined objects (`Array.prototype` in this case), i left that part of your solution in. However, I added `groupByProperties` as a non-enumerable property of `Array.prototype` so it doesn't appear in `for..in` enumerations.

Comment: Great! But some tests shows that forEach method much slower than for loop with predefined length. You disagree? =)

Comment: Indeed, forEach may be about 5 times slower than a for loop. It's still pretty fast and I for one am a fan of writing clearly and optimizing the bottlenecks if needed.

Comment: The same issue is with creating a local variable that stores the length of the array you're looping over. It is probably a lot faster to access local variable than array.length, but when you're iterating that is not the bottleneck, so a loop with saved variable is about as fast as a regular loop with array.length. (The exception to that rule is when length is not a static property, but computed on the fly, like in a live NodeList).

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is to use [_lodash.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) or [_lodash.keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy):

1. You will only have to write few lines of code to achieve same result:

   ```
   const Results = _.groupBy(list, 'lastname')
   ```

   This will group your results by last name. However in your case you need to group by multiple properties - you can use [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022156/underscore-js-groupby-multiple-values/13869056#13869056) to enchant this function.
2. Of course you can use this code multiple times.
3. Lodash allows you to install its modules one-by-one (npm i lodash.groupby);

I believe in this way you will get shorter, more maintainable code with clear functions. I guess this is an alternative.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: It might not be a code solution, but right now you don't have any explanation for **why** those functions should be used, other than "simply clean code", which doesn't explain anything.